# Finding last number generated by a sequence before it got deleted

Tags: oracle, sequence, oracle12c, database-administration

We found that there is a sequence "_SEQUENCE" is not present in one of our client's UAT instance. We don't how it got deleted and when. It is a very crucial sequence because the numbers generated by this sequence are used as unique column values in many tables across DB. In other words, no two columns (of specific column types) in any two tables in the DB will have the same number as value. On few of these columns, we have unique index also.

We can create the sequence again but we don't know what should be the initial value of the sequence because we don't know what was the last number the old sequence generated. If we set a wrong number as the initial value and by chance, if it generates the same number for the same column of a table which is already present, we may end up getting unique key violation exception.

We can set the initial value to a very big number but that is the last option. Now;

1. Is it possible to find the last number the sequence "_SEQUENCE" generated before it got deleted?
2. Is it possible to find which process deleted the sequence "_SEQUENCE" and when?

Comment: Why is setting the initial value to a very big number the last option?

Comment: Do you know all table columns that are populated through that sequence? If yes, you could generate a script to retrieve the highest number of all columns. Or use some dynamic SQL

Comment: It is nearly impossible to find where it has been used. Because this sequence is part of our internal framework. The application we are having is using the framework. On top of that many customizations are available for the client. This sequence is used in many places where ever the logic needs a number which is unique across DB. In addition to that, it is an on-premise setup and we don't have much access to their resources.

Comment: @MarcinWroblewski, as a first option, if we are able to find the last number the sequence served we would like to continue from there. Otherwise, we will set the initial value for the sequence with a big number.

Answer (score 0):

The flashback operation is not available for a sequence, while it's available for tables. A mechanishm might be produced by the contribution of a `DDL` trigger mostly created in `SYS` or `SYSTEM` database users. As an example consider this procedure :

```
create or replace procedure pr_ddl_oper as
  v_oty          varchar2(75) := ora_dict_obj_type;
  v_don          varchar2(75) := ora_dict_obj_name;
  v_evt          varchar2(75) := ora_sysevent;
  v_olu          varchar2(75) := nvl(ora_login_user,'Unknown Schema');
  v_sql          ora_name_list_t;
  v_stm          clob;
  v_sct          owa.vc_arr;
  n              pls_integer;
  n_max          pls_integer := 10000; -- max number of rows for CLOB object 
                                       -- to hold object's source.
begin
      v_sct(1) := 'SESSIONID';
      v_sct(2) := 'IP_ADDRESS';
      v_sct(3) := 'TERMINAL';
      v_sct(4) := 'OS_USER';
      v_sct(5) := 'AUTHENTICATION_TYPE';
      v_sct(6) := 'CLIENT_INFO';
      v_sct(7) := 'MODULE';
      for i in 1..7
      loop
       v_sct(i) := sys_context('USERENV',v_sct(i));
      end loop;
      select decode(v_sct(1),0,null,v_sct(1)),decode(upper(v_sct(3)),
            'UNKNOWN',null,v_sct(3)) 
        into v_sct(1),v_sct(3) 
        from dual;

       n := ora_sql_txt( v_sql );
      if n > n_max then
       n := n_max;
      end if;
      for i in 1..n
      loop
       v_stm := v_stm || v_sql(i);
      end loop;

       insert into log_ddl_oper(event_time,usr,evnt,stmt,sessionid,ip,terminal,os_user,
         auth_type,object_type,object_name,client_info,module_info)
       values(sysdate,v_olu,v_evt,v_stm,v_sct(1),v_sct(2),v_sct(3),v_sct(4),v_sct(5),
         v_oty,v_don,v_sct(6),v_sct(7));
end;
```

which could be called by this trigger as to be a future reference  :

```
--| Compiling this trigger, especially for Production Systems, should be handled with care |

create or replace trigger system.trg_admin_ddl before ddl on database
declare
begin
 pr_ddl_oper;
end;
```

By connecting SYS user you can query the `last_number` column for your dropped Sequence :

```
select last_number
  from dba_sequences 
  as of timestamp to_timestamp('2018-11-27 23:50:17', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') s 
 where s.sequence_name = 'MYSEQ';
```

where the timestamp value could be detected by

```
select l.event_time 
--> returns to_timestamp('2018-11-27 23:50:17', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
--> to use for the above SQL Select statement
  from log_ddl_oper l
 where l.object_name = 'MYSEQ'
   and l.evnt = 'DROP'
```

Comment: Thanks, Barbaros Ozhan. I'll check and update here if it works.